# pycharm does not start in Ubuntu after reboot

Tags: java, python, ubuntu, pycharm

I was using pycharm on Ubuntu fine, until I restarted the system to make some updates. Then I cannot start Pycharm anymore. I tried to start from terminal and it gives error "Unrecognized VMoption 'MaxPermSize=350m'".

I suppose this is something to do with the Java...? I have read that the latest version of Java does not work for Pycharm or something before... maybe it got "updated" automatically to the latest version when I restarted the system? Please advise me how I can start my Pycharm... thanks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/624199/problem-with-java-while-trying-to-run-pycharm-community-4-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link (https://askubuntu.com/questions/624199/problem-with-java-while-trying-to-run-pycharm-community-4-5) says to:

> Open the file `pycharm64.vmoptions`
>
> ```
> nano /opt/pycharm-community-4.5/bin/pycharm64.vmoptions
> ```
>
> and add a `#` at the beginning of the line
>
> ```
> # -XX:MaxPermSize=350m
> ```
>
> Open the file `pycharm.vmoptions`
>
> ```
> nano /opt/pycharm-community-4.5/bin/pycharm.vmoptions
> ```
>
> and add a `#` at the beginning of the line
>
> ```
> # -XX:MaxPermSize=250m
> ```

Comment: thank you very much. I was aware of the link but I had problems modifying the file as they require administrative right... now I found a way to do it and it is done.